# Highchart Java export image

Tags: java, javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to generate chart image using highchart export server. This code returns me text/html instead of image. Not sure what is going wrong here.

```
package com.vidyartha;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class CreateChart {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://export.highcharts.com");


        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        try{

            String str="{'xAxis': {'categories': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']},'series': [{'data': [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]};";
            String dataString = "{type:image/png,options:" + str+"}";
             post.setEntity(new StringEntity(dataString, 
                     ContentType.create("application/json")));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();


        String filePath = "E:\\pdf\\rakesh.png";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));

        int inByte;
        while((inByte = is.read()) != -1) fos.write(inByte);
        is.close();
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("Got Repsonse");
        System.out.println(response);


        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: your code doesnt write anything to the image  ? should i add anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending the correct [parameters](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/52-serverside-generated-charts#post-param).  You need to construct a POST request with form data of:

```
options = {'xAxis': {'categories': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']},'series': [{'data': [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}
type = image/png
constr = Chart
```

I tried this in [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

After changing String str="{'xAxis': {'categories': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']},'series......"   code returns me text/html

Answer (score 0):

If you want export chart , you can to make use this example  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xola139/y8kwg5Lh/3/)   , exist a part where to did use

```
var imageData = $(this).highcharts().createCanvas();
```

I hope will be useful